# Erro ao rodar o Tomcat do Maven

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat

Estou dando uma estudada no Spring usado o Maven, ao tentar rodar o Tomcat com o comando `mvn tomcat:run` dá um erro que não acontece quando eu rodo ele no Tomcat7 configurado no Eclipse.

O erro é esse:

> ```
> GRAVE: Servlet /spring4-webmvc threw load() exception
> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1116)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:993)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4350)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4659)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded.start(Embedded.java:825)
>     at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.startContainer(AbstractRunMojo.java:558)
>     at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:255)
>     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
>     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
>     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
>     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
> ```

O arquivo `pom.xml` esta assim:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Sera que falta adicionar mais algum plugin ou dependência?

Comment: Tente alterar: 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

Para:

    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Não deu certo, deu o mesmo erro.

Comment: Você está rodando pelo Eclipse esse comando? Se sim, não deve colocar o mvn na instrução. E o comando deve ser `tomcat7:run`.